# Why Does Thin-Film Interference Manifest Visibly Only on Thin Films?

Tags: optics, interference

We know that thin-film interference creates colors by constructive and destructive interference of different wavelengths.  One of the better images I refer to is this:
[image: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/phyopt/interf.html]

Though the example only traces one ray of light, a different ray striking at `C` can be seen to interfere with the first, so having just the original ray interfere with itself, completely neglecting the distance `CD`, is reasonable.

The path length through the medium results in different phase shifts for different wavelengths, ultimately resulting in different interference for different colors.

My question is, **why don't we see this happen in thicker materials**?

I have a guess:

> For thicker materials, variation in surface perfection results in a wide range of light paths (a small change in `A` results in large changes in `B`, which results in even larger changes in `C`), so everything averages out.  This effect is strengthened by dispersion.
>
> If this is the case, are there examples of thick materials constructed with sufficient precision to show interference?

Comment: John - I thought the same thing when I read it. I like this question because of the diagram. I don't know whether "closing as duplicate" will let the question continue to exist - it would be good to link to it from the other question.

Answer (score -1):

You don't see it happening with thicker films because the size of pupil of your eyes is finite (about 3mm) and as the layers become thick the distance between the 2 rays reaching your eyes increases so both of them cannot enter your pupil and there is no interfernce.

Comment: As I wrote, since rays strike in parallel, the difference between the incident and exitent point is negligible under uniform lighting.  In any case, interference begins at the surface, not in your eye . . .